# Communicate between python and node.js with node-icp

Tags: python, node.js, ipc

I am running a node-ipc server with the following code. I created a socket to which external programs (python in my case) should connect.

```
var ipc = require('node-ipc').default;
ipc.config.id   = 'world';
ipc.config.retry= 1500;
ipc.serve(
    function(){
        ipc.server.on(
            'message',
            function(data,socket){
                ipc.log('got a message : '.debug, data);
                ipc.server.emit(
                    socket,
                    'message',
                    data+' world!'
                );
            }
        );
    }
);
ipc.server.start();
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is to execute a python script that can connect to the socket, I have created, and send a message.

The Problem is that I do not know what kind of library is the best to use on python side to send a message to my Node.Js application. I have tried with multiprocessing but I do not know how to set up the client correctly to correspond to node-ipc.

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Client
import time
conn = Client(('localhost', 6000), authkey=b'secret password') #no sure what to set up
conn.send('message')
conn.close()
```

Is there a change necessary on my python code or node code?
What else could I try?